tsconfig file throws cannot find module after a package.json for either pre-script or build-script
In my Next.js 14.2.3 app trying to get branding (logo assets) from a CDN on a prerun and prebuild but for some reason when I place my script in a directory outside of app along with other directories referenced in tsconfig.json I get a typescript error when running.
the error:

error TS2307: Cannot find module '@api/logos' or its corresponding type declarations.

package.json
"private": true,
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "branding": "tsc utils/branding.ts && node utils/branding.js",
  "prerun": "npm run branding",
  "dev": "npm run prerun && next dev",
  "prebuild": "npm run branding",
  "build": "npm run prebuild && next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
},

branding.ts
path: root/utils/branding.ts
contents:
'server only'

import { getLogos } from '@api/logos'

//
;(async function () {
  const data = await getLogos()
  console.log({ data })
  console.log(true)
})()

tsconfig.json
path: root/tsconfig.json
contents:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@api/*": ["./api/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./types/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "sanity-studio"]
}

I know I don't have an issue with the API or API types because I can modify branding.ts to:
'server only'

//
;(async function () {
  console.log(true)
})()

in page.tsx I can build it out as
path: root/app/page.tsx
contents:
import { getLogos } from '@api/logos'

export default async function HomePage() {
  const logos = await getLogos()
  console.log({ logos })

  return <main>home page</main>
}

and the branding.js file is generated in root/utils/ plus it will log true before build and all the string URLs after build.
Why when trying to run a pre-run and pre-build script from package.json I get an error of cannot find module?
Looking at a pre setup so I can dynamically generate the favicon and other branding items before running the build process to write to the public directory.
Is there a better approach to getting API data on a pre-run or pre-build for all branding items in a Next.js app if this approach is not possible?
